# XPath "and" Confusion

Tags: xpath

I recently started a new job that uses cucumber/Gherkin along with selenium. I was trying to create a XPath for a specific element. The xml looks slightly like this...

```
<p>
  <div class="slds-text-title_bold slds-m-bottom_x-small ncc-input-label">
    Amp
  </div>
  <div class="slds-text-title_bold slds-m-bottom_x-small ncc-input-label required-field-label">
    Voltage
  </div>
</p>
```

I am looking to only get the div with the required field label in the class and text of "Voltage" So far this kinda works...

```
//div[contains(text(), "Voltage")] | //*[contains(class, "required-field-label")]
```

however I'm getting way too many false positives. Any time I change the pipe into "and" I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

HCSloan

Comment: your xpath seems to be working correctly, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression on your actual code, and see if it works:

```
//div[contains(@class, "required-field-label")][contains(text(), "Voltage")]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can match the element using "and" like this:

`//div[contains(@class, 'required-field-label') and contains(text(), 'Voltage')]`